# Increasing wifi bandwidth using two router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

Is it possible to join two routers under single SSID to increase wifi bandwidth? Suppose, there are two routers, one is N300 Mbps(with 2 5dbi antena) and other is N150 Mbps (with 1 5dbi antena) and both support WDS. Can these two routers provide bandwidth of (300+150) = 450 Mbps working together?

Comment: WDS decreases throughput in direct coverage, so I wouldn't recommend enabling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up two routers with the same SSID, same credentials, etc., but this won't give you additive bandwidth.  When your wireless device is in the range of one of the Access Points (AP - your wireless router), then it will have the respective benefits of that AP.

Comment: But if the client device  is in the range of both of the Access Points then how will it decide which one to connect, because both have same SSID.

Comment: This answer goes into more detail than I can fit into this comment:

http://superuser.com/a/844606/590746

The short of it is that how they decided is ultimately up to your device, but factors such as signal to noise will play a heavy role.  It is possible that your devices may decide to only associate with the device with the N300 router, unless it is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

No, because you can only connect to a single AP at any one time.

Comment: I didn't ask about connecting a client to multiple AP.I asked about whether it is possible to combine two routers under one SSID so that a client will connect to only a AP but will be able to use bandwidth of both routers.

Comment: The bandwidth is only available once associated with an AP and you can only associate with one AP at a time.

Comment: @DAF: You're confusing "AP" and "SSID". An AP (access point) is the radio device, so _both routers_ are acting as APs, no matter if they have identical (E)SSIDs or not. Thus "can only use one AP" means "can only be connected to one router".